# Как по умолчанию открывать Swagger/index, вместо Index.chtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

При запуске проекта (.Net Core MVC) открывается как обычно Index.chtml . Как по умолчанию открывать интерфейс Swagger для теста методов.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы вы уточнили, что именно используете: Swashbuckle или NSwag, а также какую версию ASP.NET Core, можно было бы дать более точный ответ.

Например, см. [Add and configure Swagger middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware), подраздел Tip.

Добавьте строку кода

```
c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
```

и Swagger UI будет открываться по пути корня приложения.